# How to load data from database in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.
I want to load data from my database in a ListBox, I did many searches but I don't find anything where Entity Framework is used.
In fact, I tried many solutions but always VS didn't accept the syntax.

This my model Class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Profile_Ga
    {
        [Key]
        public string ID_Gamme { get; set; }
        public string In_Ga { get; set; }
        public string Out_Ga { get; set; }
        public string Next_Gamme { get; set; }
        public string Etat { get; set; }
 }
}
```

I want to display ID_Gamme in a listBox? 
In the view I did like this by it is not accepted.

```
<%: Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ID_Gamme) %>
```

There is any solution?

Answer (score 0):

`ID_Gamme` is a string (a singular value), so you can't make a list box for a singular value.

My guess is that you need a `List<Profile_Ga>` (or IEnumerable) to do the binding. Check your Entity classes, they should have a collection property for one of the classes you need.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i change the ID_Gamme to (public string[] ID_Gamme { get; set; }) and this is what i  have in my entity class : (public DbSet<Profile_Ga> Profil_Gas { get; set; }) 
How may i change it please ?